# If there is no value to a key i want a text saying no

Tags: angularjs

I using this to get the value of responses.
[{{quest.response[key]}} responses]

When there is no response value i should display it has No Responses.

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
[{{quest.response[key] || "no"}} responses]
```